# React test state value after update in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, chai, react-state

I need to test the state change after a useEffect

FooView.jsx :

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    calculatedTotal = calculateTotal(page.paymentSchedule);
    setTotal(calculatedTotal);
}, [
    page.paymentSchedule,
]);
```

FooView-test.jsx :

```
describe('...', () => {
    const paymentSchedule = [
        {
          count: 2,
          amount: 100,
        },
        {
          count: 3,
          amount: 200,
        }
    ];

    it('should update total when the payment schedule changes', () => {
        const container = mount(<FooView />);
        container.find('FooView').prop('paymentSchedule')(paymentSchedule);
        // what to do next
    });
}
```

I use Jest and Enzyme.
How do I test the resulting state value ?

Comment: Please show minimal, complete code. How did you use the `total` state? What's `calculateTotal`?

Comment: "calculateTotal" calculates the payment shedule total amount. In this case it should be 800 (2x100 + 3x200). As for the "total" it is displayed on an input field on the screen. What I want to do is to test that the "calculateTotal" has been called after I update the paymentSchedule. And test that it's equal to 800.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set another UseEffect like this one:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(total)
}, [total]);
```

Like that, on each change done to `total` via `setTotal` will be returned in your console